# makeReferenceObject in harmonize flow - how to use the object reference?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

In the DHF tutorial on harmonizing products and orders, products are included into orders by reference using SKU:

https://marklogic.github.io/marklogic-data-hub/tutorial/harmonizing-order-data/

```
// or a reference to a Product
products.push(makeReferenceObject('Product', order.sku));

...

function makeReferenceObject(type, ref) {
  return {
    '$type': type,
    '$ref': ref
  };
}
```

An example of the harmonized order record:

```
"Order": {
  "id": 1,
  "products": [
    { "Product": {
      "$type": "Product", 
      "$ref": "12345"
    }},
    { "Product": {
      "$type": "Product", 
      "$ref": "54321"
    }}
  ],
  "price": 100
}
```

Now how can we make use of the product object reference in the order record? Should the `entity service` built-in function such as `es.instanceJsonFromDocument` be able to resolve the references and incorporate the product information into the output? Or it is just a reference for developers to implement their own custom logic?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the information in the entity service documentation. It states that the entity service APIs will simply treat such external reference as a string.

> No validation is performed on the value of an external reference. When you use the Entity Services APIs to generate code and other artifacts, the reference is treated as an opaque string.

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/entity-services/models#id_15972